# Keep Form Data after php validation (POST method)

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm validating my form with php and displaying error messsages but after every submit , the form is refreshed and the inputs are blank again . I was wondering if there was a way i could re-insert the user past data into the fields again .

I'm using POST method .

```
<form id="registration-form" action="" method="post">


<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">

<button type="submit" name="_submit" id="submit" class="button-submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

PHP function :

```
if( !isset( $_POST['_submit'] ) ){
        return array( $array, $arrayexport );
    }

$username = $_POST['username'];

// test function for username

if ( ($valid_username ) != 0 ) {

array_push($array, "Input Required"); }

else{

header( 'Location: /thankyou.php' );
}
```

Comment: add to the each field `value=" . $_POST[field_name'] . "`. You obviously need to change name of the var, and test it first with isset. Note that this way you can practice and see how the output work out, but do not use this for a real project, it's a massive security breach. You should introduce yourself to [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and other function to secure your code.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do something as

```
<input type="text" name="username" 
id="username" placeholder="Username" 
value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username'];}else{ echo '';}?>">
```

Comment: This is shorter.. `value="<?php echo @$_POST['username'];?>"`

Comment: Yes but when the form is loaded without POST then it will have un defined index and I do not prefer @ may be its used by many but seriously not recommended

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty - is there a better way to do it ? - Can i place the code in an external file instead ?

Comment: Well if u use ajax to submit the form data then you will always have data in the fields. Posting using the way u tried u need to use conditional statement to display the value in the element.

Comment: OR use some Javascript validor like jquery validator.

Answer (score 0):

made a cleaner version .

Thanks to Abhik Chakraborty

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php user()   ?>">
```

External php file :

```
function user(){
        if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username'];}else{ echo '';}}
```